# Optimize shell one liner

Tags: shell, unix

Need to optimize the UNIX shell one liner

```
cat ${TEMPFILE} | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sed '/^$/d'| sed '1,4d'| sed 's/$/|ON_ICE|OFF_ICE/g' > ${MYREPORT}
```

as this is causing performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
cat ${TEMPFILE} | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sed '/^$/d' | sed '1,4d' | sed 's/$/|ON_ICE|OFF_ICE/g' > ${MYREPORT}
```

clearly you can replace sed '1,4d' with tail +4

Answer (score 3):

Call sed only once:

```
cat ${TEMPFILE}|cut -d ' ' -f1|sed '/^$/d;1,4d;s/$/|ON_ICE|OFF_ICE/g'>${MYREPORT}
```

Comment: It should be obvious, but there's also a useless use of cat in there.

Answer (score 1):

use awk as follows:

```
awk '{$0=$1};if (NF>1){++rec}; if(NF > 1 && rec > 4 ){sub(/$/,"|ON_ICE|OFF_ICE")); print};' ${TEMPFILE} > ${MYREPORT}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^$/ || ++count <= 4 {next} {print $1 "|ON_ICE|OFF_ICE"}' "$TEMPFILE" > "$MYREPORT"
```